# Text in span element not showing after using execute_script in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have been trying to add text to an input box which is a span element.
So, after reading about how to do it.

I started using `execute_script()` method.
But even after that nothing happens.

Script:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='/home/kartikey/Desktop/Files/Text Expansion/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.example.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "email"]').send_keys('***@email')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "password"]').send_keys('****')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]').click()
# Login Complete
time.sleep(10)
# New Session Clicking
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "x-auto-4"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em/button').click()
time.sleep(10)
# Click on Easy Search Option
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "menuRoot__menuRoot_menuEasySearch"]/span[3]/span').click()
time.sleep(10)
# Find the span element in which text is edited
df = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "SyntacticField_TAREA")]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
# Trying to add text into span but FAILS!
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerText = "test";', df)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', df)
time.sleep(15)
# Closing the driver
driver.close()
```

The last `XPath` is a dynamic one that's why I used the `contains()` method for it.

The webpage is generated using JavaScript and the span element's `XPath` is:

```
//*[@id="SyntacticField_TAREA_-1737243078_easySearch"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span
```

I am unable to download the code as it is JS generated and can only be seen through inspect element.

The span element doesn't show any text that I try adding and nothing happens.

Comment: Is this some custom framework as text-editor or..? Span can hold the current text, but some hidden input to accept the typing, depends. But its a good approach to send the text directly to the 'innerText', search the html for some input element or give some info for the application that you are using.

Comment: When I manually enter the text "random" it is added in the span. So, I thought of sending `execute_script` to that part but it is not of any use.

Comment: For example, there is a framework 'monaco' editor, his also displaying the text in span, but you can send the text trough the console ex: monaco editor object.. or sending the text to a input element which is hidden. Try sending the text using browser actions. 
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(the editor element)
actions.send_keys(some text)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set ".value" instead of innerText? That's what I use when changing text by javascript. I also use single quotes instead of double, though I don't think that should give any issues.

```
arguments[0].value = 'test';
```

EDIT:
I just realised that I've had a few occurrences where values would not update without sending an "onchange" event. This is the full code I use:

```
public string SetElementValue(IWebElement element, string value)
{
    ScrollToElement(element);  // Other function that makes sure the element is in view
    var exec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)this;
    var script = @"
        var el = arguments[0];
        el.value = '" + value + @"';
        try 
        {
            if (""createEvent"" in document) {
                var evt = document.createEvent(""HTMLEvents"");
                evt.initEvent(""change"", false, true);
                el.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
            else
                el.fireEvent(""onchange"");
        }
        catch(err){ return err; }
        return ""Javascript executed."";
    ";
    var result = exec.ExecuteScript(script, element);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

EDIT2:
I don't have any Python experience, but I guess you would end up with something like this:

```
script='''var el = arguments[0];
            el.value = "' + value + '";
            try 
            {
                if (""createEvent"" in document) {
                    var evt = document.createEvent(""HTMLEvents"");
                            evt.initEvent(""change"", false, true);
                            el.dispatchEvent(evt);
                        }
                else
                    el.fireEvent(""onchange"");
            }
            catch(err){ return err; }
            return ""Javascript executed."";'''
driver.execute_script(script, df)
```

**Not sure if I got the syntax right**, you might need to change a few quotes here and there. Please post the correct syntax if that's the case, then we can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is `JavaScript` right? Do you have anything equivalent for `Python`?

Comment: For a better layout, I replied in the answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Selenium for this? there's maybe more elements with that same xpath:

`df.send_keys('your text')`

to check how many elements:

```
df = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "SyntacticField_TAREA")]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
print(len(df))
```

and function that check if elem is visible:

```
def check_if_visible(elements, index=0):
"""
:param elements: driver.find_element_by...
:param index: index of visible elements, it could be the same all time
:return: return index of visible elements
"""
try:
    first_visible_elem = 0
    last_visible_elem = 0
    if index >= 0:
        while elements[first_visible_elem].is_displayed() == False:
            first_visible_elem = first_visible_elem + 1
        index = index + first_visible_elem
    else:
        while elements[first_visible_elem].is_displayed() == False:
            first_visible_elem = first_visible_elem + 1
        while elements[first_visible_elem].is_displayed() == True:
            last_visible_elem = first_visible_elem
            first_visible_elem = first_visible_elem + 1
        index = last_visible_elem + 1 + index
except IndexError:
    pass
return index
```

how to use - where x is index of visible elem, if only one is visible it will be always 0:

```
df = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "SyntacticField_TAREA")]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
df[check_if_visible(df, x)].send_keys('your text')
```

Comment: check first line again :P you've got 'driver.find_element' but should be "driver.find_elements" to check it. With Selenium is the same nothing happens??

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, It returns 10 elements but `XPath` is dynamic. What should I look into?

Comment: there're three possibilities: 
1. if everytime you've got 10 elements with that same xpath you've to just find good one and do something like this where x is index of good elem: 
    *gf[x].send_keys("your text")*

2. there is not always 10 elements so you have to find another way to find elem. 
3. there is not always 10 elements but only one is displayed then you need to write function that checks visible elements.